# Difference between popl $xxxx and popl register

Tags: assembly, x86, att

```
popl  $0x3fffc0
```

I believe it's incorrect because it means that you are popping out a number rather than its address, which is what you want. Please let me know if I am understanding this correctly. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what architecture you are referring to here, and I'm not an assembly guru, but I don't think immediate value as `pop` operand is possible on most architectures.

Comment: Which architecture is this?

Comment: It's possible to `pop` to a memory address.  Could this be at&t syntax for that?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd : AT&T syntax for popping to a memory operand would be `popl 0x3fffc0` . `popl $0x3fffc0` should not be encodable.

Comment: retagged on the assumption that this is x86 with AT&T syntax.  Please correct if that's not what you meant, but no of course you can't use an immediate as a destination for any instruction.  You can use a memory address, though.